# Combine two list based on result data to create a new list in java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I want to combine two lists into a single list based on certain criteria.
Sample is the list 1 contains

```
final Org ro1= new Org(1, 1001, "Name 01");
final Org ro2 = new Org (2, 1001, "Name 02");
final Org ro3 = new Org (3, 1002, "Name 03");
final Org ro4 = new Org (4, 1003, "Name 04");
final Org ro5 = new Org (5, 1004, "Name 05");
List<Org> listOrg = new ArrayList<>();
// Add all the object to the listOrg
```

The list 2 contains

```
final Candidate can1 = new Candidate(1001, "Candidate01", "100");
final Candidate can2 = new Candidate(1002, "Candidate02", "150");
final Candidate can3 = new Candidate(1003, "Candidate03", "200");
List<Candidate > listCandidate  = new ArrayList<>();
// Add all the Candidate  object to the listCandidate
```

My final list will look like

```
List<Result > listResult  = new ArrayList<>();
// Each individual object of the listResult is followed- 
final Result rs1= new Result (1, 1001, "Name 01", "Candidate01", "100");
final Result rs2 = new Result (2, 1001, "Name 02", "Candidate01", "100");
final Result rs3 = new Result (3, 1002, "Name 03", "Candidate02", "150");
final Result rs4 = new Result (4, 1003, "Name 04", "Candidate03", "200");
final Result rs5 = new Result (5, 1004, "Name 05", null, null);
```

I want to achieve the same using Java 8 stream features. Can anyone please help me in this?

My class details

```
public class Candidate {
    private int canId;
    private String candidateName;
    private String score;
    //Getter setter with constructors.
}

public class Org{
    private int id;
    private int canId;
    private String name;
    //Getter setter with constructors
}

public class Result {
    private int id;
    private int canId;
    private String name;
    private String candidateName;
    private String score;   
    //Getter setter with constructors.
}
```

The Org class have a canId, which serves as the mapping point for the CandidateClass.

Comment: Not `new Result` for last block code ?

Comment: @azro my mistake..editing the corect one

Comment: Apparently, there is a property in `Org` that is supposed to match a property in `Candidate`. Are we supposed to guess such relationship, as well as the property names?

Comment: show us what have you tried till now and where are you stuck?

Comment: Mind showing us the class definitions of the two classes? We need the getters from the classes at least?

Comment: @HadiJ so you assume that there is a `getSecondArgumentFromConstructor()` in `Org` and a `getFirstArgumentFromConstructor()` in `Candidate`?

Comment: sure..sharing the class details

Comment: Seriously, I would simply use the traditional double `for` loop for this. Using stream API with lambdas for this is more likely to make things more complicated.

Comment: Solution are provided, can you accept one or comment if something is missing ? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like so,

```
Map<Integer, Candidate> candidateById = listCandidate.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Candidate::getId, Function.identity()));
List<Result> resultList = listOrg.stream()
        .map(o -> {
          Candidate candidate = candidateById.getOrDefault(o.getCandidateId(), new Candidate(-1, null, null));
          return new Result(o.getId(), o.getCandidateId(), o.getName(), candidate.getName(), candidate.getNum());
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

First create a `Map` of `Candidate` objects against their Id value. Then iterate over the `List` of `Org` objects, get the associated `Candidate` instance from the map given the Id value, and merge them together to form a `Result`. Finally collect all the `Results` into a `List`.

**Update**

As per the comment below, this can further be improved as,

```
List<Result> resultList = listOrg.stream()
        .map(o -> new Result(o, candidateById.get(o.getCandidateId())))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The `Result` constructor now looks like this,

```
public Result(Org org, Candidate candidate) {
        super();
        this.orgId = org.getId();
        this.candidateId = org.getCandidateId();
        this.orgName = org.getName();
        this.candidateName = Optional.ofNullable(candidate).map(c -> c.getName()).orElse(null);
        this.candidateNum = Optional.ofNullable(candidate).map(c -> c.getNum()).orElse(null);
    }
```

Comment: This cannot solve the `null` case, it'll throw NPE on .getName()

Comment: I have updated the answer, so that it can handle `null` now.

Comment: Now if `Result` had a constructor accepting an `Org` argument and a `Candidate` argument that is allowed to be `null`, the code could be really elegant…

Comment: @Holger I have updated the answer. That simplified the code significantly. Thanks a lot for the great feedback !

Comment: Thanks @RavindraRanwala for the solution. Have tried the same and works fine!

Answer (score 1):

You iterate over your `Org` and for each one you look for the corresponding `Candidate` if it exists, and then build a `Result` from both `Org` and `Candidate`, a constructor `Result(Org o, Candidate c)` would be helpful as you can see below :

To avoid to iterate the `listCandidate` each time, you can prepare them in a map to get them by `canId`

**1.** Detailled solution

```
Map<Integer, Candidate> candidates = listCandidate.stream()
                      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Candidate::getCanId, Function.identity()));
List<Result > listResult  = new ArrayList<>();
listOrg.forEach(org -> {
          Candidate can = candidates.getOrDefault(ro.getCanId(), null);
          Result r = new Result(org, can);
          listResult.add(r); 
        });
```

**2.** Short solution using `Streams`

```
Map<Integer, Candidate> candidates = listCandidate.stream()
                      .collect(Collectors.toMap(Candidate::getCanId, Function.identity()));

List<Result > listResult = listOrg.stream()
                 .map(org -> new Result(org, candidates.getOrDefault(ro.getCanId(), null)))
                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**3.** `Result` constructor to add

```
public Result(Org o, Candidate c){
    this.id = org.getId();
    this.canId = org.getCanId();
    this.name = org.getName();
    this.candidateName = c==null ? null : c.getCandidateName(); // return null if c is null
    this.score = c==null ? null : c.getScore());                // return null if c is null
}
```

Comment: That implies up to `listOrg.size()`×`listCandidate.size()` operations. Surely not recommended for larger lists.